# What is the low level process of browser-based sign in WIFI protected access?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, login, wpa

In order to protected WIFI not being connected by everybody. There is always a WIFI protected access mechanism.

Unlike WPA-PSK or WPA-Enterprise, there is another kind of authentication mechanism which is heavily used airport and the other public commercial place. This kind of mechanism use HTTPS protocol. You can open sign in page via web-browser. You can use exact the same way how you log into Websites like GitHub.com. When you signed in, there is Connect Button for you to click. Then you can access all stuff on the internet.

I don't know what this type of access protection is. But I have see it a lot of times.

i don't know how WIFI can transmit HTML or JavaScript before connection established.

Most important, What are the low level procedures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not actually a Wi-Fi mechanism. Such networks work exactly the same way as a fully open Wi-Fi network (i.e. no WPA or 802.1X or anything such), and your connection *is fully established* by the time you get the login screen.

Instead, for such "[captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal)" networks, the actual sign-in procedure is implemented at IP level – using firewall and DNAT rules. It can also be applied to Ethernet, LTE (mobile data), or any other IP-based network.

The network's gateway has a DNAT rule that redirects all DNS (port 53) traffic to its local resolver and all HTTP (port 80/443) traffic to its local web server. No matter what website you try to visit, the router's own web server always responds with a "Redirect" response pointing to the login page. (All other kinds of network traffic are just outright blocked.)

When you log in, the system adds another firewall rule that exempts your device (by its IP and/or MAC addresses) from blocking and redirection, allowing you to finally access the outside network.

Note that although sometimes the login page pops up on is own, there **isn't** any mechanism here that would force your OS to show it. Instead the OS has to probe for such login pages by itself, by attempting to make a few HTTP requests and matching them against known responses. If the OS receives an unexpected redirect response, it *assumes* that's a Wi-Fi login page and shows it to you. (Web browsers also do similar probing on their own, as otherwise such redirects would cause a "certificate invalid" error page for HTTPS websites.)